# Teradata how to Export Favourites Tab

Tags: teradata, favorites

Does anyone know if it is possible to export Favourites setup from Teradata? Is there a way to query it etc.?

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the Favorites in SQL Assistant, there's stored in

```
C:\Users\your user\AppData\Roaming\Teradata\SQL Assistant\Favorites.qbs
```